# Styles of populating and returning objects with Golang

Tags: go

In my exploration with Golang, I have encountered different ways of returning values from a method. To make this easier, I'll play off an example. Assume that we have two methods that return a single `Corgi` struct and a slice of `Corgi`.

Coming from Java/C# land, one way of achieving this is to include the value or pointer as part of the return with something like this:

```
func GetCorgi(id int) (Corgi, error) {
    // Do stuff and return a Corgi struct or error
}

func GetAllCorgis() ([]Corgi, error) {
    // Do stuff and return a slice of Corgi structs or error
}
```

However, I've noticed other APIs like App Engine and MongoDB, use this approach for some of their methods where you pass a pointer which then gets populated.

App Engine [`Get`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get)

```
func Get(c context.Context, key *Key, dst interface{}) error
```

Mongo [`One`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.One) and [`All`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Query.All)

```
func (q *Query) One(result interface{}) (err error)
func (q *Query) All(result interface{}) error
```

Which in my case may look like this

```
func GetCorgi(id int, corgi *Corgi) error {
    // Populate corgi and return error
}

func GetAllCorgis(corgis *[]Corgi) error {
    // Populate corgi and return error
}
```

Is this a matter of preference/style? Or are there advantages with one approach?

Comment: The interface{} doesn't _have_ to be a pointer, though most apis enforce it by checking whether it's a pointer.

Comment: When a method/function has an output pointer as an argument, it's because it needs some information about that argument, size, type, address, etc., so that it can populate the structure you're passing in correctly. How would `json.Unmarshal` work if you couldn't pass in a data structure to unmarshal into?

Comment: @JimB Your last sentence pretty much made me see the light. Thank you.

Comment: If generating too much garbage is a concern (like in a tight loop) then sometimes passing in a pointer that gets populated and then reused/reset is an effective optimization. In most situation I prefer returning the value directly instead.